# Testing Spring controllers using Powermock

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockito, powermock, spring-test-mvc

I have a class which tests specific controller and it works fine

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:config/test-applicationContext-config.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners({ 
    WebContextTestExecutionListener.class, 
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
public class TestAdminController {  
     //.....
}
```

I have used there Google's Mockito library from [mockito.org](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to mock my underlying beans.

**Now my question is the following:** I have some classes which need to be mocked also, but they have `final` methods and Google's mockito seems not resolving this issue. One of my collegues suggested to use Powermock from [powermock.org](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/). But it requires to annotate the tester class with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` annotation. If I use this I have to remove the annotation `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and this will give me problems cause the Spring test context will not be created. How I can avoid this situation?

After suggestion I have configured to use `PowerMockRule` instead of `@RunWith` annotation

My project Maven dependencies are as follows

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-classloading-xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now my class looks like this (another controller test)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:config/test-applicationContext-config.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners({ 
    WebContextTestExecutionListener.class, 
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
@PrepareForTest(ADSynchronizationImpl.class)
public class ThirdPartyLoginControllerTest {
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Autowired
    private ThirdPartyLoginController thirtPartyLoginController;

    @Autowired
    private MockFactoryForControllers mockFactory;

    @Test
    public void testLoginActiveDirectory(){

    }
}
```

But after running my test I'm getting the following exception trace

> com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
>   javassist.NotFoundException:
>   com.somecompany.analytics.manager.db.api.MlDao$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$b86d7415
>   : javassist.NotFoundException:
>   com.somecompany.analytics.manager.db.api.MlDao$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$b86d7415
>   ---- Debugging information ---- message             : javassist.NotFoundException:
>   com.somecompany.analytics.manager.db.api.MlDao$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$b86d7415
>   cause-exception     : java.lang.RuntimeException cause-message       :
>   javassist.NotFoundException:
>   com.somecompany.analytics.manager.db.api.MlDao$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$b86d7415
>   class               :
>   com.somecompany.ui.controllers.ThirdPartyLoginController required-type
>   : com.somecompany.ui.controllers.ThirdPartyLoginController
>   converter-type      :
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
>   path                :
>   /org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1/outer-class/fNext/fTarget/thirtPartyLoginController/mlDao
>   line number         : 14 class[1](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/)            :
>   com.somecompany.ui.controllers.ThirdPartyLoginControllerTest class[2](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) 
>   : org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod class[3]
>   : org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement class[4]
>   : org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1 version
>   : null
>   -------------------------------   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
>     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1052)    at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1036)     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:912)    at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:903)    at
>   org.powermock.classloading.DeepCloner.clone(DeepCloner.java:54)   at
>   org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:89)
>     at
>   org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:49)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javassist.NotFoundException:
>   com.somecompany.idm.analytics.manager.db.api.MlDao$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$b86d7415
>     at
>   org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:199)
>     at
>   org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:149)
>     at
>   org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.ClassLoaderReference.loadClass(ClassLoaderReference.java:31)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:49)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:45)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.determineType(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:458)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:294)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     ... 57 more Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException:
>   com.somecompany.analytics.manager.db.api.MlDao$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$b86d7415
>     at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:450)  at
>   org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:192)
>     ... 87 more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.jayway.com/2010/12/28/using-powermock-with-spring-integration-testing/) which explains how to use PowerMock and `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`. Basically, you just have to use a [special `PowerMockRule` rule](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:config/test-applicationContext-config.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners({ 
    WebContextTestExecutionListener.class, 
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
public class SpringExampleTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

}
```

Edit: it seems that [other people had the same problem](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=350) as you regarding `@PowerMockRule`. Using [PowerMockAgent](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockAgent) instead could solve your case. See also [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13043338/500478) on SO.

Comment: I have tried it, but it seems X-Stream library under powermock is bug prone which is said also in your posted article

Comment: Actually the article says XStream is more robust than Objenesis, the bugs they mention seem to appear with Objenesis. I've used XStream on other projects (not with PowerMock) and never had any problem. Did you encounter such bugs?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, after using it with spring I have got error. I have edited the post to be more clear

Comment: Could you look if you have multiple versions of Mockito in your classpath? Such errors often happen when two different classloaders load two different versions of a same dependency. `mvn dependency:tree` can help you figure this out.

Comment: Yes it seems that I had multiple versions on classpath. But after fixing that I've got another error. I have changed exception trace

Comment: I edited my answer, perhaps `PowerMockAgent` will solve your problem. Anyway, it seems to be tricky to use PowerMock in a Spring integration test :)

Comment: Thanks your posted SO answer was helpful!

Answer (score 6):

You could also try to annotate your test class with

```
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

See example [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/blob/powermock-1.6.0/examples/spring-mockito-delegate/src/test/java/org/powermock/examples/spring/mockito/SpringExampleTest.java).

Comment: Also, add the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` before the delegate part

Comment: Link of exemple dead

Comment: @jpmottin try looking inside previous versions, I was able to [find](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/blob/powermock-1.6.0/examples/spring-mockito-delegate/src/test/java/org/powermock/examples/spring/mockito/SpringExampleTest.java) this file for 1.6.0 tag.

Comment: Thanks @gce  can you update the provided link in the original message ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use JMockit instead of Powermock. It can do everything Powermock can do, and it doesn't need an @RunWith clause so it doesn't interfere with your Spring test runner. I found that the PowerMockRule introduced more problems than it solved...