# JUnit method level Category does not work with PowerMockRunner

Tags: junit, powermock

Given this Test Class

```
    @PowerMockIgnore("UnitTest")
    @Category(UnitTest.class)
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    public class SomeClass {

       @Test
       @Category(SlowTest.class)
       public void SlowMethod(){...}
    }
```

And a Test Suite

```
   @RunWith(Categories.class)
   @SuiteClasses({AllUnitTestSuite.class})
   @ExcludeCategory(SlowTest.class)
   public class FastUnitTestSuite {

   }
```

When I run the FastUnitTestSuite it runs the SlowMethod also despite it is in SlowTest Category.
I can exclude slow Test Classes using PowerMockIgnore and multiple categories. How could I exclude the slow test methods while using PowerMockRunner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use `PowerMock` with a different test runner, you should use the [powermock junit rule: `PowerMockRule`](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule).

You could see an example with a [`SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224807/1594933).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you gontard! Here is what I changed:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*" })
@Category(UnitTest.class)

public class SomeClass {

   @Rule
   public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule(); //it has to be public

   @Test
   @Category(SlowTest.class)
   public void SlowMethod(){...}
}
```

I had to add these libs also to my classpath: powermock-module-junit4-rule, powermock-classloading-base, powermock-classloading-xstream, xpp3_min

Answer (score 1):

This issue due to below line in Categories. CategoryFilter file under method hasCorrectCategoryAnnotation

```
if (fIncluded == null || fIncluded.isAssignableFrom(each))
```

- this will fail even though the class type is same or under inheritance because `fIncluded` is loaded by Categories classloader and `each` is loaded by PowerMockRunner class loader.

Probably we need fix this logic