# Mock class without PowerMock in arquillian Test

Tags: java, mockito, jboss-arquillian

I would like to now, if it is possible to mock a class like

```
public class MyClass{
   ...
}
```

Our business logic create this object with `new myClass()` somewhere in the code and therefore I don't have access to the created object to mock those methods. Is  there a way to replace the whole class or to overwrite those methods. I'm using *mockito* and I only found examples to do this like

```
@Test
public void myTest{
    MyClass myClass = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
    Mockito.when(myClass.myMethod()).thenReturn("hello World");
    ...
}
```

We can't use PowerMock because it isn't compatible with our test environment.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The above code mocked the class MyClass. You want to test the methods inside MyClass or what you are trying to TEST?

Comment: @MinhKieu I want to mock a class, not just an instance, because `new MyClass()` isn't called inside the test function

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i see only two hardcore solutions:

Make Powermock working by using PowerMockRule and PowerMock Rule Agent:
[Getting javassist not found with PowerMock and PowerRule in Junit with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190377/getting-javassist-not-found-with-powermock-and-powerrule-in-junit-with-mockito/21483526#21483526)

or

Use Java Reflection to set the mocked object to MyClass: [Is it possible in Java to access private fields via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555658/is-it-possible-in-java-to-access-private-fields-via-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

I found a passable way to achieve my requirement.

I converted *MyClass* to a bean, just add annotation `@Dependent`.

```
@Dependent
public class MyClass{
   public Integer someMethod(){
       return 100;
   }
}
```

I use *MyClass* in business logic like that

```
public class BusinessClass{
    @Inject
    MyClass myClass

    public Integer doSomething(){
        return myClass.someMethod();
    }
}
```

After this change I'm able to mock the class in my test with annotation `@Specializes`

```
@Specializes
@Dependent
public class MyClassMock extends MyClass
{
    @Override
    public Integer someMethod(){
        return 23; // return my mocked value
    }
}
```

*MyClass* will be automatically replaced with *MyClassMock* in testenvironment.